# Why are they traveling with Ursa?

Tags: plot-explanation, after-earth

I didn't get why they are travelling with Ursa in [*After Earth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1815862/). And what is their desired travel plan (obviously not earth)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the Ursa was on the ship for training purposes. It was there for the ship's crew to try and learn more about the creatures and train other rangers to "ghost". Ultimately, when the ship crashed, it escaped.

As for their intended travel plan, I don't think it was ever alluded to, aside from being Cypher's "last voyage". Ultimately they get caught up in the asteroid shower, take a jaunt through a wormhole and voila - Earth. It clearly wasn't their intended destination, not least given Cypher's reluctance to even set down there.

So effectively:

1. Ursa was there to train rangers to ghost.
2. Unclear what their original travel plan was (and unnecessary to story, thus why it's not discussed in more detail).